# How to remove files with multiple extensions

Tags: python

The following code does not work and is also overly verbose and redundant. What is the best way to fix it?

```
if os.path.exists('*.obj'):
    os.remove('*.obj')
if os.path.exists('*.dll'):
    os.remove('*.dll')
if os.path.exists('*.exe'):
    os.remove('*.exe')
if os.path.exists('*.manifest'):
    os.remove('*.manifest')
if os.path.exists('*.pch'):
    os.remove('*.pch')
if os.path.exists('*.lib'):
    os.remove('*.lib')
if os.path.exists('*.rsp'):
    os.remove('*.rsp')
if os.path.exists('Makefile'):
    os.remove('Makefile')
```

Comment: maybe a post for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since when `os.path.exists` and `os.remove` started working with glob patterns?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm just about to ask...

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary: See edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to use `glob`:

```
from glob import glob

patterns = ('*.obj', '*.dll', '*.exe', '*.manifest', '*.pch', '*.lib', '*.rsp', 'Makefile')
for p in patterns:
    for f in glob(p):
        os.remove(f)
```

Answer (score 7):

[`os.remove`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove), [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) accept a file path, not a pattern.

Using [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), you don't need to check file existence.

```
import os

exts = ('.obj', '.dll', '.exe', '.manifest', '.pch', '.lib', '.rsp')
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
    if fn.lower().endswith(exts) or fn == 'Makefile':
        os.remove(fn)
```

---

[`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) accepts tuple; can be used to check extension:

```
>>> 'file.exe'.endswith(('.obj', '.dll', '.exe', '.manifest'))
True
>>> 'file.com'.endswith(('.obj', '.dll', '.exe', '.manifest'))
False
```

---

Using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
# set literal
exts = {'.obj', '.dll', '.exe', '.manifest', '.pch', '.lib', '.rsp'}
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.splitext(fn)[-1].lower() in exts or fn == 'Makefile':
        os.remove(fn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to match the file names. The following generates the one needed given the names of the extensions and any specific file names. Once this is compiled, it's simply a matter of applying the compiled re's `match()` method to each candidate file name to determine whether to remove it or not.

```
import os
import re

dirpath = './testfiles'
exts = ('obj', 'dll', 'exe', 'manifest', 'pch', 'lib', 'rsp')
fns = ('Makefile',)

pattern = '|'.join(r'.+\.{}$'.format(re.escape(ext)) for ext in exts)
if fns: pattern += '|' + '|'.join(re.escape(fn) for fn in fns)
fnpat = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE if os.name == 'nt' else 0)

for fpath in (os.path.join(dirpath, fn)
                for fn in os.listdir(dirpath) if fnpat.match(fn)):
    os.remove(fpath)
```